# Qual a diferença entre git pull e git fetch?

Tags: git

Se ambos os comandos trazem código do repositório remoto, posso usar qualquer um dos dois? Tem alguma diferença entre usar `git pull` e `git fetch`?

Answer (score 0):

Git pull traz as alterações do servidor remoto, git fetch sincroniza as mudanças entre os commits pendentes para envio da sua máquina e as alterações que estão no servidor remoto.